# Add UIHint to Property created with Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, entity-framework

I have a model created with Entity Framework (from my database). This has given me an auto-generated Partial Class with all the required Properties.

I want to add a UIHint data annotation to one of these properties, but I don't want to add that code into the auto-generated file.

Is there a way of adding a UIHint to an existing property via another Partial Class? Or am I missing a fundamental part of how to use MVC?

## UPDATE

juhan_h's answer worked perfectly, but here it is in VB.NET in case it helps anyone:

Generated class

```
Partial Public Class MyEntity
    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property Name As String
End Class
```

Metadata class

```
<MetadataType(GetType(MyEntity_Metadata))>
Partial Public Class MyEntity
End Class

Class MyEntity_Metadata
    <DisplayName("Key of the entity")>
    Public Property Id As Integer
    <UIHint("MyTextBox")>
    Public Property Name As String
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use associated metadata classes to decorate your automatically generated classes with additional attributes.

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidebb/archive/2009/07/24/using-an-associated-metadata-class-outside-dynamic-data.aspx) is an article describing the concept that should be applicable to your situation as well.

**Example**

Generated class

```
public partial class MyEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Metadata class

```
[MetadataType(typeof(MyEntityMetadata))]
public partial class MyEntity
{
}

class Product_Metadata
{
    [DisplayName("Key of the entity")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [UIHint("MyTextBox")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I do not really speak VB.NET so the examples are in c# but they should be easy to convert to VB.

Comment: Worked like a charm, I'll update my question with the VB.NET example in case it helps anyone. Thanks again!